Varnish unable to Cache Magento 2.4.3
Continuing my issue from this thread.
I think it's not caching due to Cache-Control header. Firstly, let me share my updated VCL configuration below maybe my VCL has an issue somewhere.
vcl 4.0;

import std;
include "./vars.vcl";
include "./pagespeed-requirement.vcl";

sub vcl_recv {
if (req.restarts > 0) {
    set req.hash_always_miss = true;
}

if (req.http.host ~ "www.domain1.com" || req.http.host ~ "domain1.com") {
    set req.backend_hint = domain1;
    return (pass);
} else if (req.http.host ~ "www.domain2.com" || req.http.host ~ "domain2.com") {
    set req.backend_hint = domain2;
} else if (req.http.host ~ "career.domain3.com") {
    set req.backend_hint = career;
    return (pass);
} else {
    set req.backend_hint = default;
    return (pass);
}

if (req.url ~ "^/.well-known/") {
  return (pass);
}

# Remove the proxy header to mitigate the httpoxy vulnerability
# See https://httpoxy.org/    
unset req.http.proxy;


if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    if (client.ip !~ purge) {
        return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
    }
    
# capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
    if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
        return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
    }
    if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
      ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
    }
# ban everything to catch assets as well
    if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern == ".*") {
      ban("req.url ~ .*");
    }
    if (req.http.X-Pool) {
      ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
    }
    return (synth(200, "Purged"));
}

if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "https") {
    set req.http.location = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
    return (synth(750, "Permanently moved"));
}

if (req.method != "GET" &&
    req.method != "HEAD" &&
    req.method != "PUT" &&
    req.method != "POST" &&
    req.method != "TRACE" &&
    req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
    req.method != "DELETE") {
      /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
      return (pipe);
}

# We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
    return (pass);
}

# Bypass customer, shopping cart, checkout
if (req.url ~ "/customer" || req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/payment" || req.url ~ "/reclaim" || req.url ~ "/search" || req.url ~ "/order-confirmation-summary") {
    return (pass);
}

# Bypass health check requests
if (req.url ~ "/health_check.php") {
    return (pass);
}

# Set initial grace period usage status
set req.http.grace = "none";

# normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

# collect all cookies
std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

# Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|webp|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv|webp)$") {
        # No point in compressing these
        unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
    } else {
        # unknown algorithm
        unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
}

# Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
}

# Static files caching
if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
    # Static files should not be cached by default
    return (pass);

    # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
    #unset req.http.Https;
    #unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
    #unset req.http.Cookie;
}

# Authenticated GraphQL requests should not be cached by default
if (req.url ~ "/graphql" && req.http.Authorization ~ "^Bearer") {
    return (pass);
}

return (hash);
}


sub vcl_hash {
    if ((req.url !~ "/graphql" || !req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) && req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
    hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
}

# For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
if (req.http.host) {
    hash_data(req.http.host);
} else {
    hash_data(server.ip);
}

# To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
    hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
}

if (req.http.cookie ~ "currency=") {
set req.http.X-TMP = regsub(req.http.cookie, ".*currency=([^;]+);.*","\1");
hash_data(req.http.X-TMP);
unset req.http.X-TMP;
}

if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
    call process_graphql_headers;
}
}

sub process_graphql_headers {
if (req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
    hash_data(req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id);

    # When the frontend stops sending the auth token, make sure users stop getting results cached for logged-in users
    if (req.http.Authorization ~ "^Bearer") {
        hash_data("Authorized");
    }
}

if (req.http.Store) {
    hash_data(req.http.Store);
}
if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
    hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
}
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
set beresp.grace = 3d;

if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
    set beresp.do_esi = true;
}

if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
    set beresp.do_gzip = true;
}

if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
    set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
}

# cache only successfully responses and 404s
if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
    set beresp.ttl = 0s;
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    return (deliver);
} elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
    return (deliver);
}

# validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
    if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
        set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
    }
} else {
    unset resp.http.Age;
}

if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
} else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
}

# Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
    set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
    set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
    set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
}

unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
unset resp.http.Server;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
unset resp.http.Via;
unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_synth {
if (resp.status == 750) {
    set resp.http.location = req.http.location;
    set resp.status = 301;
    return (deliver);
}
}

sub vcl_hit {
if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
    # Hit within TTL period
    return (deliver);
}
if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
    if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
        # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
        set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    } else {
        # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
        return (restart);
    }
} else {
    # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
    set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
    return (deliver);
}
}

We need to focus on domain2, the Cache-Control headers in response headers are max-age=0, no-cache, no-store. No custom code has cacheable=false in Magento's app/code directory. Hence, I don't know how is this being added.
I commented the following lines in vcl_backend_response and was able to see X-Cache: HIT on the browser only for the / home page. Other page's don't have this parameter at all.
 if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

Upon checking the logs for command:
varnishlog -g request -b -i BeReqUrl -I BerespHeader:Cache-Control \
    -I BerespHeader:Expires -I BerespHeader:Vary -I BerespHeader:Set-Cookie \
    -I BerespHeader:Surrogate-Control -i TTL -q "TTL[6] eq 'uncacheable'"

I get following result for the main domain/home page. (https://www.domain2.com).
**  << BeReq    >> 65569     
--  BereqURL       /
--  BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, s-maxage=60
--  TTL            RFC 60 10 0 1724061342 1724061342 1724061342 0 60 cacheable
--  TTL            VCL 60 259200 0 1724061342 cacheable
--  TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1724061342 cacheable
--  TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1724061342 uncacheable
--  BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding

Also, there are no logs if I click on another category page or product, it's as there was never made a request and x-cache is also missing in response headers. Probably all other pages/paths are being bypassed.
Update:
Below are my transaction logs for homepage on refresh.
*   << Request  >> 5         
-   Begin          req 4 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1724150405.424135 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1724150405.424135 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 35242 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      Host: www.domain2.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: www.domain2.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: 1.1.1.1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.1
-   ReqHeader      Ssl-Offloaded: 1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Ssl: on
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      cdn-loop: cloudflare
-   ReqHeader      cf-ipcountry: PK
-   ReqHeader      accept-encoding: gzip, br
-   ReqHeader      cf-ray: 8b61c9c7cf07be84-SIN
-   ReqHeader      cf-visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
-   ReqHeader      cache-control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua: "Not)A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="127", "Chromium";v="127"
-   ReqHeader      accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   ReqHeader      upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-site: same-origin
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-dest: empty
-   ReqHeader      accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      priority: u=0, i
-   ReqHeader      cf-connecting-ip: 1.1.1.1
-   ReqHeader      cookie: ajs_anonymous_id=0ef0-485a-ae6a-d03d649b79e6; _gcl_au=1.1.1724011616; _fbp=fb.1.1724011616211; _hjSessionUser_3574595=56yfdvdvdvgfrvvd
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.1, 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      PS-CapabilityList: ll,ii,dj,jw,ws:
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqUnset       accept-encoding: gzip, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   HitMiss        3 115.365105
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 6 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1724150405.585118 0.160983 0.160983
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Server: nginx
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   RespHeader     Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2024 10:40:05 GMT
-   RespHeader     X-Page-Speed: ngx_pagespeed
-   RespHeader     Link: </RootCmp_CMS_PAGE__default.9b247fcd07254236f444.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
-   RespHeader     Link: </RootCmp_CMS_PAGE__default.9b247fcd07254236f444.js.gz>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
-   RespHeader     Link: </runtime.8f084be222019779ec78.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
-   RespHeader     Link: </vendors.2510f870ac43c344ee54.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
-   RespHeader     Link: </client.7a54ea122b5c72f16096.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 5
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.5)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespHeader     X-Cache: MISS
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespUnset      Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Server: nginx
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 5
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.5)
-   RespUnset      Link: </RootCmp_CMS_PAGE__default.9b247fcd07254236f444.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
-   RespUnset      Link: </RootCmp_CMS_PAGE__default.9b247fcd07254236f444.js.gz>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
-   RespUnset      Link: </runtime.8f084be222019779ec78.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
-   RespUnset      Link: </vendors.2510f870ac43c344ee54.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
-   RespUnset      Link: </client.7a54ea122b5c72f16096.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1724150405.585169 0.161034 0.000051
-   Filters        
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 72801
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1724150405.585305 0.161170 0.000135
-   ReqAcct        2066 0 2066 377 72801 73178
-   End            
**  << BeReq    >> 6         
--  Begin          bereq 5 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1724150405.424291 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
--  BereqHeader    Host: www.domain2.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: www.domain2.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: 1.1.1.1
--  BereqHeader    Ssl-Offloaded: 1
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Ssl: on
--  BereqHeader    cdn-loop: cloudflare
--  BereqHeader    cf-ipcountry: PK
--  BereqHeader    cf-ray: 8b61c9c7cf07be84-SIN
--  BereqHeader    cf-visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua: "Not)A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="127", "Chromium";v="127"
--  BereqHeader    accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
--  BereqHeader    upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
--  BereqHeader    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-site: same-origin
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-mode: navigate
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-dest: empty
--  BereqHeader    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
--  BereqHeader    priority: u=0, i
--  BereqHeader    cf-connecting-ip: 1.1.1.1
--  BereqHeader    cookie: ajs_anonymous_id=0ef0-485a-ae6a-d03d649b79e6; _gcl_au=1.1.1777705759; _fbp=fb.1.1724011616211; _hjSessionUser_3574595=242424v24vhvgv
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.1, 127.0.0.1
--  BereqHeader    PS-CapabilityList: ll,ii,dj,jw,ws:
--  BereqHeader    grace: none
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 6
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  BackendOpen    29 domain2 127.0.0.1 8084 127.0.0.1 33002 reuse
--  Timestamp      Bereq: 1724150405.424392 0.000100 0.000100
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1724150405.580200 0.155909 0.155808
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   200
--  BerespReason   OK
--  BerespHeader   Server: nginx
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
--  BerespHeader   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
--  BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
--  BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
--  BerespHeader   Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2024 10:40:05 GMT
--  BerespHeader   X-Page-Speed: ngx_pagespeed
--  BerespHeader   Link: </RootCmp_CMS_PAGE__default.9b247fcd07254236f444.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
--  BerespHeader   Link: </RootCmp_CMS_PAGE__default.9b247fcd07254236f444.js.gz>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
--  BerespHeader   Link: </runtime.8f084be222019779ec78.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
--  BerespHeader   Link: </vendors.2510f870ac43c344ee54.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
--  BerespHeader   Link: </client.7a54ea122b5c72f16096.js>; rel=preload; as=script; nopush
--  BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
--  TTL            RFC 0 10 0 1724150406 1724150406 1724150405 0 0 cacheable
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
--  TTL            VCL 0 259200 0 1724150406 cacheable
--  TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1724150406 cacheable
--  TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1724150406 uncacheable
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Filters         esi_gzip
--  BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
--  BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Fetch_Body     2 chunked -
--  Gzip           G F E 98588 72801 80 582328 582338
--  BackendClose   29 domain2 recycle
--  Timestamp      BerespBody: 1724150405.585110 0.160819 0.004910
--  Length         72801
--  BereqAcct      2091 0 2091 668 0 668
--  End


Based on the log output, it seems like the following header is causing the so-called Hit-For-Miss:
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, s-maxage=60

Although the s-maxage header is set to 60 seconds, it's the no-cache statement that makes this response uncacheable.
Analyzing the log output
Let's analyze the output of the TTL tag in the logs.
Here's the spec for the TTL tag as explained on https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vsl.html:
%s %d %d %d %d [ %d %d %u %u ] %s
|  |  |  |  |    |  |  |  |    |
|  |  |  |  |    |  |  |  |    +- "cacheable" or "uncacheable"
|  |  |  |  |    |  |  |  +------ Max-Age from Cache-Control header
|  |  |  |  |    |  |  +--------- Expires header
|  |  |  |  |    |  +------------ Date header
|  |  |  |  |    +--------------- Age (incl Age: header value)
|  |  |  |  +-------------------- Reference time for TTL
|  |  |  +----------------------- Keep
|  |  +-------------------------- Grace
|  +----------------------------- TTL
+-------------------------------- "RFC", "VCL" or "HFP"

Let's apply this to the first occurrence of the TTL tag:
--  TTL            RFC 60 10 0 1724061342 1724061342 1724061342 0 60 cacheable

According to the RFC standards a max-age or s-maxage value was set to 60 seconds. Initially this makes the response cacheable for 60 seconds.
--  TTL            VCL 60 259200 0 1724061342 cacheable

Later on in the VCL code, the Grace value is set to 3 days, which equals 259200 seconds. The TTL tag mentions this, and the response is still cacheable.
--  TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1724061342 cacheable

However, at some point a change in the VCL happens and the TTL is set to 120 seconds. This is caused by a set beresp.ttl = 120s; statement in the VCL.
--  TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1724061342 uncacheable

But that override in the VCL also does a set beresp.uncacheable = true; to make the response uncacheable.
To find the VCL code that triggers this behavior, you have to look for the a condition that results in the following statements:
set beresp.ttl = 120s;
set beresp.uncacheable = true;

Your VCL code has these and the no-cache check is probably the one that causes this.
Next steps
There a couple of ways to approach this problem:

You look for the Magento code that sets the no-cache directive in the Cache-Control header and ensure the no-cache is removed there.
You acknowledge the fact that the no-cache directive is there for a reason and you either accept the cache miss, or you remove the component/feature that triggers the no-cache
You write the VCL code that identifies this pattern and you store the object in the cache despite the no-cache directive.

It is entirely possible there's more to the story than what you described. In that case, I'd like to see the entire log transaction, including both the client transaction and the backend transaction. This can shed even more light on the situation.

@Feryn I have almost checked several times and magento isn't unnecessary adding "no-cache" to headers. I even modified the upward.yml configuration which adds additional headers and made sure no-cache wasn;t there. But didn't help. Please tell me how can I produce the entire transaction logs for frontend and backend?

Assuming you want to capture logs for the homepage, this is the command: varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'". For cache misses, this command will capture both the client logs and backend logs.

@Feryn I have updated my question with the transaction logs.

The output is very clear: --  BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache. Your backend is returning a Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, which prevents Varnish from caching the response.

@Feryn can you please tell me what is meant by `-   RespUnset      Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache

RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0`
In the request.


@nix That's your VCL stripping of the Cache-Control header and replacing it with another value prior to sending it to the client. Remember: web browsers also respect Cache-Control headers. Your VCL code specifically mentions that it wants avoid that browsers cache non-static content. This isn't really something that will impact Varnish's caching.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
